# How to display product view page in custom module Popup in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, module, product-view

In my custom module, I have created a Popup and I want to display product view page in the popup. Is there any possible way to do this?

Please help me how to achieve this ASAP?

Comment: http://www.weltpixel.com/advance-product-quick-view.html

Comment: why dont you use a free plugin http://www.magebuzz.com/quick-view-for-magento-2.html , and customize as per your need

Comment: I am using quick view extension. But I need to implement zoom image on hover functionality that is not working in Quick view but it's already on my product view page. So , that's why i want to display my product view page in Popup. Is it possible ?

Comment: Please help me on this.

Comment: @VishwasBhatnagar Can you help me in this ?